# something messy with enable-app-engine-project

Tags: python, google-app-engine, oauth-2.0, google-bigquery, google-api-python-client

I'm following this tutorial
https://developers.google.com/bigquery/articles/dashboard#downloadinstalllibraries

Here they say that

```
cd source/
enable-app-engine-project hellodashboard/
```

which will copy some 60 files into the project directory.But i saw only some 10 files copied.And the oauth2client folder in project directory only has `__init__.py`file
Since i'm using

```
from oauth2client.appengine import oauth2decorator_from_clientsecrets
```

When i run my program it shows an error

```
from oauth2client.appengine import oauth2decorator_from_clientsecrets
ImportError: No module named appengine
```

So i manually copied all files from oauth2client zip  to the project oauth2client directory.
Now when i run my program it doesn't show any error and seems to run fine.Is it some thing messy with the enable-app-engine-project command or am i doing some thing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`enable-app-engine-project` tries to locate sources based on the path(s) where the modules are installed on your local system. Have you installed these modules locally?

As an alternative, you can simply copy the following directories into your App Engine project manually:

```
SOURCES = [
    'gflags',
    'gflags_validators',
    'httplib2',
    'oauth2client',
    'oauth2',
    'apiclient',
    'uritemplate',
    ]
```